# Yes or No while loop for a 2d array doesn't print array in C

Tags: c

I'm new to c and don't really understand how 2d arrays work. When the code is executed it prompts for me to enter a course and then when the loop is broken the print statement doesn't show what I inputted.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>

    int main()

   {

   char courses[60][100];
   char ans ='y';
   int  i=0;
   int p,j;

   while (ans == 'y'){
   printf("Enter course:\n");
   for (p=0;p<j;p++)
   scanf("%s", &courses[p]);
   getchar(); 

   i++;

  printf("Would you like to enter another course? (y or n) \n"); 
  ans = getchar();

 }
 printf("courses are %s",courses[p]);
 }
```

Comment: Correcting your indenting would make the code more readable

Comment: You created an array of characters and not pointers.   Pointers are used to reference “strings” of characters.   I’m not sure what `j` does and is currently not set or manipulated so you’ll likely run into storage corruption.

Comment: `printf("courses are %s",courses[p])` outputs *one* string, but the code does not enter any data for `courses[p]`, only up to `courses[p-1]`.

Comment: In addition to the unintialised `j` value, the last `printf` is also wrong. `p` is not a valid index at that point and if you want to print out all the courses you need another `for` loop to print each of the `courses` strings.

Comment: Link123, did you write this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int main()
{
    char courses[60][100];
    char ans ='y';
    size_t  i = 0;

    do
    {
        printf("Enter course:\n");
        scanf("%99s", courses[i]);
        getchar(); 
        i++;
        printf("Would you like to enter another course? (y or n) \n"); 
        ans = getchar();
    }while(ans == 'y');
    for(size_t p = 0; p < i; p++)
        printf("courses are %s\n",courses[p]);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/EKqEq8aos

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica and `courses[i]` not `&courses[i]`. Copy paste